# How to create a StreamController that has different Data Types for the Input & Output

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, stream

I want to create a `StreamController` that accepts an Input from a specific **Data Type**, for example `double` and provides another **Data Type** as an output, for example `String`?

Example:

```
30.0 ---> [STREAM CONTROLLER] ---> "$30.00 USD"
```

Answer (score 0):

To create this logic, you can chain to `StreamController`s together to get something like this:

```
Input Data ---> [FIRST CONTROLLER] ---> ⚙ ---> [SECOND CONTROLLER] ---> Output Data
```

Here is the recipe for that :

1. Create two `StreamController`s, the first from the `type` of the **Input Data** and the second from the `type` of the **Output Data**.
2. Chain the controllers by listening to the **First One**, mapping the data, and then add it to the **Second One**.
3. Use the **First Controller** `sink` to add the data and the **Second Controller** `stream` to get the data.

Code Example ‍: (**NOTE**: This code implements the same logic in the question example)

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  // Streams Setup:
  final priceInputController = StreamController<double>();
  final priceOutputController = StreamController<String>();
  
  priceInputController.stream.listen((price){
    final priceAsString = '\$${price.toStringAsFixed(2)} USD';
    priceOutputController.sink.add(priceAsString);
  });
  
  priceOutputController.stream.listen((price){
    print(price);
  });
  
  // Usage:
  priceInputController.add(30);  
}
```

Output:

```
$30.00 USD
```

That's it

**NOTE:** You can find & run this code example directly at `DartPad` from this [link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=df3aafca4cdfe81cafb96678a8839cd3).

Comment: no need for `listen` / `add` - there is a `Stream.pipe` method - for example: `doubleCtrl.stream.map((i) => '$i usd').pipe(stringCtrl.sink)`